# How to add Language localization in .net 5 web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, localization, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I have tried to follow the steps of [this tutorial](https://www.waretec.at/localizing-asp-net-core-5-apis-statically-typed/) to Apply Language localization at my API level.
but what ever the HTTP request Header is, it alwase brings the default Language.
this is the startup Code, in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
  #region Localiztion
        services.AddLocalization();
        services.AddRequestLocalization(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");

            x.ApplyCurrentCultureToResponseHeaders = true;

            x.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> {
                new("ar"),
                new("en") 
            };

             x.SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> {
                new("ar"),
                new("en")
            };

        });
        #endregion
```

at `Configure` method :

```
  app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

the resources :

[image]

I have tried to add `culture` header as mentioned in the tutorial or adding `Content-Language` header as mentioned on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) but still, it only brings the default whatever the default is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After A bit of research, the HTTP header that works with the localization was `Accept-Language`.